Jackson: Passing context to custom serializer through ObjectMapper
I have an annotation that uses a custom serializer:
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target(ElementType.FIELD)
@JacksonAnnotationsInside
@JsonSerialize(using = MaskingSerializer.class)
public @interface JsonMask {
}

And the serializer:
public class MaskingSerializer extends JsonSerializer<String> {

    @Override
    public void serialize(String value, JsonGenerator jsonGenerator, SerializerProvider serializerProvider) throws IOException {
        jsonGenerator.writeString(RegExUtils.replaceAll(value, ".", "*"));
    }
}

I only want the serializer to replace the String with * only some of the time. I was hoping there was a way to provide context to the ObjectMapper that would then be useable by the serializer.
I tried:
SerializationConfig serializationConfig = objectMapper.getSerializationConfig();
serializationConfig.getAttributes().withAttribute(MaskingSerializer.JSON_MASK_ENABLED_ATTRIBUTE, Boolean.TRUE);
return objectMapper
    .setConfig(serializationConfig)
    .valueToTree(entity);
}

and in the serializer:
if (serializerProvider.getConfig().getAttributes().getAttribute(JSON_MASK_ENABLED_ATTRIBUTE) == Boolean.TRUE) {
    jsonGenerator.writeString(RegExUtils.replaceAll(value, ".", "*"));
} else {
    jsonGenerator.writeString(value);
}

but getAttributes() always has an empty ContextAttributes. I also tried .withPerCallAttribute() and .withSharedAttribute() but neither worked.
Is there a way to pass context to a serializer through the ObjectMapper at the time of serialization?

With help from the Jackson community:
When calling the ObjectMapper:
return objectMapper
            .writer()
            .withAttribute(MaskingSerializer.JSON_MASK_ENABLED_ATTRIBUTE, Boolean.TRUE)
            .writeValueAsString(entity);

and in the serializer:
if (serializerProvider.getAttribute(JSON_MASK_ENABLED_ATTRIBUTE) == Boolean.TRUE) {
        jsonGenerator.writeString(RegExUtils.replaceAll(value, ".", "*"));
} else {
        jsonGenerator.writeString(value);
}

